# Adding SharePoint file URLs to QnA maker via REST API not working

Tags: sharepoint, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am trying to create a Flow/Power Automate which will add document URLs from a SharePoint Online library to QnA maker Knowledge Base once a document is uploaded. Following actions are working -

- Through QnAMaker website, I'm able to add SharePoint file URLs successfully.
- I am able to call a REST API patch operation to add a public URL to QnA Maker knowledgebase.

However, when I try to add a SharePoint file URL to QnA maker via the same REST API, the link doesn't get added to the KB. But, I get a proper response (202 Accepted). I think its due to authentication prompt issues.

Any thoughts how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Currently we support only public urls and SharePoint urls, Here is the doc for sharepoint urls (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/add-sharepoint-datasources).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/reference-document-type-url

If it's internal url work around is that to somehow make a public endpoint for this url to extract the qna pairs.

Comment: My issue is not being able to add SharePoint URLs through REST API. As mentioned, I am able to add SharePoint-hosted documents through the QnA maker portal without issues.